# Alternatives to partial mantel test for removing spatial autocorrelation in R?

Tags: r, spatial-correlation

I have a presence/absence distance matrix based on eDNA sampling for certain species at ~30 sites.  I would like to see if the volume of water filtered influences species detection, accounting for the fact that sites that are geographically close together are more likely to share common species.  My first thought was to construct distance matrices for geographical distance, filter volume, and species presence, and conduct a partial mantel test.  However, upon further reading, it seems that this is frowned upon in the ecological community, and tests that use raw data for geographical distance and environmental variables are more favorable, but I haven't been able to identify a particular test.  Are there alternatives to the partial mantel test in R that would accomplish this, or is the partial mantel sufficient?